# Java script jquery ajax request returning _pronto_ data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a get request using jquery ajax I am getting  data as below How to get only address I dont need the _pronto data

```
 $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:function(data){
                 var address=   getNormalizedAddress(data)  ;
                    localCache.set(url,address) ;
                    onSuccess(address);

                },

                error: wrapErrorHandler(onError, " : Url = " + url + " : Stack = " + new Error().stack),
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                timeout:defaultTimeoutInMS,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                headers: {'Authorization': "53635656"}

   response   data:
    address: Array[151]
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: `_pronto`? Do you mean `_proto_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the address field from the returned data:

```
success:function(data){
        var address = getNormalizedAddress(data.address);  //not clear whether you will need this
             localCache.set(url,data.address) ;
             onSuccess(data.address);
}
```

_proto is present on all objects as it is part of javascript. you can ignore it